# multipartFormDataとAnyContent 両方のrequestを取得したい

Tags: scala, playframework

画像アップロード後遷移する処理なのですが、

```
Action(parse.multipartFormData) {implicit request =>
```

でrequestを取得すると、request[MultipartFormData[files.Temporaryfile]]
の型になり、viewに渡す際、

```
Cannot find any HTTP Request here
```

とエラーが出ます。

multipartFormDataとAnyContent
両方のrequestが取得したいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あっているかはわかりませんが、自己解決しました。

```
Action{implicit request=>
```

でAnyContent型のリクエストを取得し、その後

```
 var r = AnyContentAsMultipartFormData.apply(request.body.asMultipartFormData.get).mdf
```

MultipartFormDataに変換し、動作を確認しました。